# Java remove strings that include new line

Tags: java

I have some HTML like:

```
<ul>
  <li>First Test (EOL)
  </li>
  <li>Second Test</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to remove the FIRST li component WITH the EOL character.

I've tried this (I also used single escape on the \r and \n):

```
        String returnString = theHTMLFromMethod;
        String test = "<li>" + firstWord + " " + secondWord+ "(\\\\r|\\\\n)" + "</li>";
        System.out.println(test);
        returnString = returnString.replaceAll(test, "");
```

But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 1. What is `returnString`? 2. How many times are you escaping those poor characters? A EOL is `\r\n`, nothing else.

Comment: Sorry - returnString is the HTML generated. And I double escaped the characters so that when it got in the regex replace, it would use \\n instead of \n. I tried both either way to no success.

Comment: might try this http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjfh90CDA/index.html, "<li>(.*)$(\\s)*</li>" DISCLAIMER: im not the best regex builider...

Comment: I think the general consensus is to not try to parse HTML with regex. Try using a special HTML library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example:

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sourceString = "PREFIX <li>Some text\n</li> SUFFIX";
    String regularExpression = "<li>Some text(\n|\r|\r\n)</li>";

    System.out.println("Source string: " + sourceString);
    System.out.println("Regular expression: " + regularExpression);

    System.out.println("Eval result: " + sourceString.replaceAll(regularExpression, ""));
}
```

}